# GameObject[] , List<GameObject>, Custom Inspector in EditorWindow unity c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have problem with displaying `GameObject[]` array and `list<T>`

in my `EditorWindow` and this is my code :

```
public class WaypointItem
{
    public List<GameObject> AllEnemys = new List<GameObject>(); // Enemies to kill
    public GameObject[] Objectman; // object to spawn
}
```

I want to display it in my `EditorWindow`

```
public class WaypointItemEditor : EditorWindow
{
//Display Objectman[] here.
// Display  AllEnemys list here.
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What have you tried? Please explain more

Comment: It looks like this is caused by lack of code ;)

Comment: I don't know how to display lists in With A Custom Editor Script

Comment: perhaps use scriptable objects?

Comment: @SotirisTsartsaris, 
I have :

WaypointItem.cs
`[ System.Serializable] 
public class WaypointItem{ 
public GameObject[] Objectman; 
}`

WaypointItemList.cs :
`public class WaypointItemList : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<WaypointItem> WaypointsList;
}
`

WaypointItem.cs:
`[CustomEditor(typeof(WaypointItemList))]
public class WaypointInItemEditor : Editor
{public WaypointItemList WaypointItemList;
//Here i want to display WaypointItemList.Objectman
//Here i want to display WaypointItemList.WaypointsList
}`

I don't know how to create custom list with Unity Editor.